# Is there a way to adjust the time displayed by the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, clock

I'm just curious...on the status bar on the home screen and the lock screen, is there a way to change the time that is displayed??? I've been trying to find things on this both in SDK 3.2 and 4 but with no luck.

Thanks for any responses! I really appreciate them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You generally can't affect phone-wide features like that, nor does Apple allow you to confuse the user in such a manner.

Comment: Thank you! I figured that I should ask since I did something like this for a Blackberry app that I made :P